# Popping messages from Ruby Queue in a proper way

Tags: ruby, queue, fifo

Here is my code to send messages from [Queue](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html):

```
def initialize
    @messages = Queue.new
end

def send_messages_from_queue
    while msg = @messages.pop(true)
        #Pushing data through websocket
    end
rescue ThreadError
    #raised if queue is empty
end
```

It works but has one drawback: if there are no channel subscribers the message is not being sent but still taken out of the `Queue` and therefore goes lost.

How to take last message from Queue but not delete it from there until it is sent?

I could expose the inner queue:

```
@messages.class.module_eval { attr_reader :que }
```

or

```
@messages.define_singleton_method(:first_message) do
   @que.first
end
```

but it is not the right way and also has it's own drawback:

when I take a message out of Queue in one thread using `pop`, it won't be available for other thread few milliseconds later, but when I use the custom `first_message` method, the message will be available for any other thread until I call `pop`.

Comment: sorry, Paul, my bad, I'd never used Queue before.  nice question